# Why am I getting EditText.getText()' on a null object reference?

Tags: android, user-interface, expandablelistview

I'm building an app that displays an alert dialog at FAB click, takes the user input and names an ExpandableListView group header with that user input.  When I click the FAB button and put in the text, it gives me a null object reference.

I've initialized my semester before the `onCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter;
    private FloatingActionButton addItems;
    private String semester = "";
```

In my `addItems()` method, which is called when there is a FAB click, I am creating my custom Alert Dialog, getting the user input String and placing it in my ArrayList in the adapter.

```
public void addItems() {
        final EditText et_semester = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_semester);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Create A Semester");
        builder.setView(R.layout.custom_layout);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                semester = et_semester.getText().toString();
                adapter.groupNames.add(semester);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        builder.show();
    }
```

But when I click the DONE button on the AlertDialog, this is my stacktrace:

```
05-30 05:35:10.295 20943-20943/myapp.onur.expandablelistviewexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: myapp.onur.expandablelistviewexample, PID: 20943
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at myapp.onur.expandablelistviewexample.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
```

**EDIT** This is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter;
    private FloatingActionButton addItems;
    private String semester;

    int counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);

        adapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        addItems = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_items);

        final EditText et_semester = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_semester);
    }

    public void addSemester(View v){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Create A Semester");
        builder.setView(R.layout.custom_layout);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final EditText et_semester = (EditText).findViewById(R.id.et_semester);
                semester = etSemester.getText().toString();
                adapter.groupNames.add(semester);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your onCreate method

Comment: move    `final EditText et_semester = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_semester);` to `OnCreate` method

Comment: @lelloman Its up there.

Comment: @JohnJoe I did and it still yields the same error.

Comment: place  `addItems = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_items);`  before   `expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);`

Comment: You are not calling `addItems` method in `onCreate`.

Comment: @JohnJoe I placed my entire MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText R.id.et_semester is not in your activity content view, So you must find this view directing in your dialog view

```
    // Inflate your view
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    // Bind views
    final EditText et_semester = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_semester);
    // Create dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Create A Semester")
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: do I initialize dialogView in my `addItems()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Hank Moody's answer was correct.  This is what I did.

```
public void addSemester(View v){

        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        final EditText et_semester = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_semester);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Create A Semester");
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                semester = et_semester.getText().toString();
                adapter.groupNames.add(semester);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        builder.show();
    }
```

Calling the method `addSemester()` in `onCreate()` is not a good idea because there are certain settings in the method that are triggered through the FAB click but if you place it in the `onCreate()` method, they run the moment the activity is created.